# How can I modify the CSS of WordPress "Amadeus" Theme to be centered?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having real difficulties centering and aligning a theme in Wordpress called "Amadeus". The website is [heidikaloustian.com](http://www.heidikaloustian.com/bio/). I want the width of .content-area which is 740px and center it, the menu should be left aligned and the menu right aligned within it according to the mockup. Help, what am I missing?

Mockup of centered design;
[image: Mockup of centered design]

Comment: Please include code in your question. Providing a link to an active site has too problems: it is a moving target as you try and fix it adn it makes the question irrelevant to people viewing the question once the problem is resolved. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to best ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you:

```
/* Line 1117 in style.css */
.site-header {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 740px;
    margin: auto;
}
/* Line 1199 in style.css */
.site-content {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 740px;
}
```

Since your content is limited to 740px I set the entire page content and header to that width and it gives the look you show in your mock-up.

Comment: Awesome. I just checked this out with the developer console an it works pretty much as expected for center-aligning. I did a change which is changing from width to max-width in order to make sure the website stays responsive.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following:

```
#page {
    width: 740px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-header {
    display: flex;
}

.main-navigation {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.main-navigation li {
    padding: 14px;
}
```

You will need to remove the container class from the site header and from the main-navigation.
Also remember to add the flexbox prefixes, in case you're going to support other browsers.